# CPU recommendation for a GPU workstation, the following Intel comparison?

Tags: processor

I am looking at getting a CPU from the following list:

- Intel Xeon E3-1220v6
- Intel Core i5-7600
- Intel Core i5-7600K

[Here is a comparison of these CPUs on the Intel website for your convenience.](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/compare-products.html?productIds=97470%2C97150%2C97144)

I will be building a small form factor desktop GPU workstation (AI, ML, Computer Vision development) with an NVIDIA Quadro P600. I've narrowed it down to the CPU's in the above comparison. They are all pretty similar in price and specs, but what would you all choose if it were you?

On a side note, I'll mainly be using Linux / Windows but I'd like to possibly use this as a hackintosh, so let me know if any one of these is incompatible there, but not really that important if it's not.

Comment: Instead of linking to an external resource, which can go out of date or die, you should include the relevant bits directly in your question.

Comment: I agree, and have updated, and I prefer SEJPM's edit that includes the external link. Using the StackExchange format for hardware recommendations is going to include a lot of one-off questions like this. Unless there is an integrated way to display component information that is kept up-to-date, it is not going to be very convenient for either askers or answerers if external links result in a downvote.

Comment: Just to be clear - external links *are* okay, but the relevant bits should be included in the post just in case the link dies. If it doesn't, awesome, and then it doesn't matter if the details in the post go out of date - it's a contingency backup, rather than an authoritative source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If you want to use ECC (error checking and correcting) RAM, you *have to* get the Xeon. If you don't want to use ECC, which is more expensive than normal RAM.

If you don't want to get your own CPU cooler, but rather want to use a stock one, get the i5-7600 because it is the only one from that list that can be shipped with a stock Intel air cooler.

In any other case the i5-7600K is the superior choice.

- It has a higher TDP, meaning it can clock higher for longer.
- It has an integrated GPU (as opposed to the Xeon) which can be used to dedicate the Quadro to data-crunching.
- It can easily be over-clocked given appropriate cooling.
- It has a higher default clock than the other CPUs.